# AND OR AND CAML query in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, caml

Can't figure out a good way to do this. I have a view in SharePoint that I want to filter using a query like (A and B) or (A and C). I'm trying to write this in CAML in Sharepoint Designer but am getting nowhere. This is my first time using CAML so that's not helping. Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
<Where>
           <And>
                <Or>
                     <And>
                          <Eq>
                               <FieldRef Name="Component" />
                               <Value Type="Text">ComponentX</Value>
                          </Eq>
                          <Eq>
                               <FieldRef Name="Review_x0020_Canceled" />
                               <Value Type="Boolean">0</Value>
                          </Eq>
                     </And>
                </Or>
                <Eq>
                     <FieldRef Name="Component" />
                     <Value Type="Text">ComponentX</Value>
                </Eq>
                <IsNull>
                     <FieldRef Name="Actual_x0020_Finish_x0020_Date" />
                </IsNull>
           </And>
      </Where>
```

I'd like this to display all records where (Component=ComponentX AND Review Canceled=No) or (Component=ComponentX AND Actual Finish Date=Null)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<Where>
  <Or>
    <And>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Component' />
        <Value Type='Text'>ComponentX</Value>
      </Eq>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Review_x0020_Canceled' />
        <Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value>
      </Eq>
    </And>
    <And>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Component' />
        <Value Type='Text'>ComponentX</Value>
      </Eq>
      <IsNull>
        <FieldRef Name="Actual_x0020_Finish_x0020_Date" />
      </IsNull>
    </And>
  </Or>
</Where>
```

[image: will return the record with the blue background color]

new code caml:

```
<Where>
  <And>
    <And>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Review_x0020_Canceled' />
        <Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value>
      </Eq>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Component' />
        <Value Type='Text'>ComponentX</Value>
      </Eq>
    </And>
    <IsNull>
      <FieldRef Name='Actual_x0020_Finish_x0020_Date' />
    </IsNull>
  </And>
</Where>
```

Comment: This doesn't get the result I'm looking for. Using this query, SharePoint still returns records where Actual Finish Date is not null.

Comment: Then in your filter, you want to present is always null? Or only when you have the registration Component = componentX?

Comment: I only want to see records where (component=componentx AND review canceled=no) OR (component=componentx AND actual_finish_date=null). It seems to be filtering out the "review_canceled records correctly but it still shows records that have an actual finish date. Does it have something to do with the Actual_Finish_date field being a date field?

Comment: I think I see what the issue is. It's how I'm explaining the logic. I want to see all records where review_canceled=no OR actual_finish_date=null. But I only want to see them if the component=componentX. I think your solution works for the logic I provided, but the logic was probably incorrect.

Comment: So your logic this should be the same:
Component = componentX And (Review Canceled = NO OR Actual Finish Date = NULL)
Did you see the picture above? Only this returning records with blue background

Comment: Ok. The first record there should not be returned because review_canceled=true. Also the fifth record shouldn't be returned because actual finish is not null.

Comment: excuse the delay in responding.
Only you want only the second record, your filter has to be only AND, a look at the code above

Answer (score 0):

Your logic

```
(Component = ComponentX AND Review Canceled = NO) OR 
    (Component = ComponentX AND Actual Finish Date = NULL)
```

is equivalent to

```
Component = ComponentX And (Review Canceled = NO OR Actual Finish Date = NULL)
```

which would be this CAML query:

```
<Where>
  <And>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="Component" />
      <Value Type="Text">ComponentX</Value>
    </Eq>
    <Or>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="Review_x0020_Canceled" />
        <Value Type="Boolean">0</Value>
      </Eq>
      <IsNull>
        <FieldRef Name="Actual_x0020_Finish_x0020_Date" />
      </IsNull>
    </Or>
  </And>  
</Where>
```

Comment: This doesn't get the result I'm looking for. Using this query, SharePoint still returns records where Actual Finish Date is not null.